# Bogus intent action

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity started from an Intent in a notification - works just fine. Using exactly the same code, but changing the target class to a different activity, I get this error in the logcat:

```
DEBUG/Posts(5919): Bogus intent action: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.controlj.copame/.Posts bnds=[103,68][697,154] (has extras) }
```

The target activity does not show. However I can quite happily invoke it directly from a different activity via startActivity(), or via an IntentFilter.

What does "Bogus intent action" mean? Google is no help.

Comment: Have you added the activity to the manifest? (I don't know what Bogus intent action is..)

Comment: best logcat message ever haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the problem was that I was creating an explicit Intent, but also setting an action:

```
resultIntent = new Intent(COPAService.this, Threads.class);
resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
```

however this worked fine until the target Activity had an intent-filter specified.